# Site access blocked for certain browsers

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, ios

[image]

I get that screen above when accessing http://www.nait.ca from chrome, but not from firefox.

I get that screen on four different computers running Mac Yosemite  and three browsers Chrome, Safari, curl

curl -k (go ahead with insecure certificates) works.

Tried rebooting the router.  No change.

Additional info
 * Happens in incognito windows too.
 * Happens on 4 different computers with different users and extension sets.
 * Happens on two different OS's
 * Happens in 4 out of 5 browsers.

Does not happen when my nephew in Ottawa accesses the site using Chrome on Windows, nor Safari on iPhone.

I get the same message (in text)  if I use curl.

How and why would chrome be blocked, but not firefox.

After posting this, I saw that I had answers to a question on academia.SE

[image]

I suspect the two are related.  Once again, it's fine on Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One computer is used as a caching dns server using pdnsd Our router passes out this machines address for the 8 machines on our home network.  Problem vanished after rebooting that computer.

I've been unable to repeat the problem.

For next time:

Check to see what IPs a problem website shows.  Repeat this between steps to see if it changes.

Stop and start pdnsd.

Flush the cache of psnsd.  (p is for persistent -- It remembers the last 10,000 or so.  I have configured an aggressive caching policy to compensate for a very slow Internet link.

This theory didn't even occur to me until I needed to reboot that computer for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This server is using Azure, and looks like its being loadbalanced.  Most likely one (or more) of the nodes is overworked and is not handling any more requests.

Its possible/probable that they are doing cookie/session based routing, and your different browsers have different cookies, so they are going to different systems.   In short, this is a SERVER problem, and one or more servers in the server cluster is having an issue.

Comment: That was my first thought, and in other circumstances it is a good one (hence upvote.)  If this were the case however, it wouldn't work on firefox, and people outside my LAN would also have the problem.

Comment: Try getting a plugin for to change the user agent and see if that fixes ) creates the problem. Maybe it's a combination of IP range and routing for certain browser strings. That you are getting a blue screen with white writing from Azure indicates this is a server side problem (or deliberate action)

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reason might be that you are using Proxy settings for local addresses. To resolve the issue please follow the steps given below:

Go to Chrome Settings-->Settings-->Click on Show Advance Settings-->Network-->Click on Change Proxy Settings-->LAN Settings-->Enable Bypass proxy server for local Address.

To get a more clear view please have a look at the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: On a mac it's not laid out like this.  Proxy is under system, and opening proxy settings brings up System preferences.  Trying to figure how how this would affect multiple computers but only one browser.

Comment: No proxies are set.  Enable bypass for local is set, along with 169.254/16

Comment: Go to chrome://extensions and check if there are any extensions that have higher privileges than other ones, for example those who "Can access URL's" and "Change what you see" type of extensions.

Comment: Happens in incognito windows too.  Happens on 4 different computers with different users and extension sets.  Happens on two different OS's

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your router from your router IP?

Comment: Tried that.  No change.

Comment: Any chance your ISP blocked the site for whatever reason. Have you tried VPN just to test it out?